# Update multiple elements with ref value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i have documents containing list of grades and students
every student has grade ref to grades document

```
 [
  {
   _id: ObjectId("5d49d1c622ffbb2764e4daf4"),
   title:'Grade 1',
   next:ObjectId("5d4b405e41cff30a6002bf6a")
  },
  {
   _id: ObjectId("5d4b405e41cff30a6002bf6a"),
   title:'Grade 1',
   next: ObjectId("5d62d5b0b421db43f8dffd6c") 
  },
  {
   _id: ObjectId("5d62d5b0b421db43f8dffd6c"),
   title:'Grade 1',
   next:"null"  
  }
 ]
```

and another containing students

```
[
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d82be276c414710424ba909"),
 name:'jone',
 "grade" : ObjectId("5d49d1c622ffbb2764e4daf4"),
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d8373566c414710424ba90b"),
 name:'adam',
 "grade" : ObjectId("5d4b405e41cff30a6002bf6a"),
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d83d59b6c414710424ba910"),
 name:'alise',
 "grade" : ObjectId("5d62d5b0b421db43f8dffd6c"),
}
]
```

i want to write update query to update all students grade to next grade where found in his grade to be as this result

```
[
 {
 "_id" : ObjectId("5d82be276c414710424ba909"),
  name:'jone',
  "grade" : ObjectId("5d4b405e41cff30a6002bf6a"),
 },
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5d8373566c414710424ba90b"),
  name:'adam',
  "grade" : ObjectId("5d62d5b0b421db43f8dffd6c"),
 },
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d83d59b6c414710424ba910"),
  name:'alise',
  "grade" : null,
 }
]
```

Comment: Can you post what output you are looking for?

Comment: update students collections grade to be grade.next value

Comment: could you give example of expected output

Comment: please review question i add expected output